# How can I get the date of the last Full Crawl in Sharepoint 2010 using Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, web-crawler

I can run the following to get the current crawls and from there determine the last crawl completed date.

```
# Get the Search App from Sharepoint
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "My Search Service"
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $searchapp 

$contentsource = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource "MyCrawl" -SearchApplication $searchApp
$contentsource.CrawlCompleted
```

But this is the last time *any* crawl completed.  I want the date of the last *Full* crawl.

I can see the information in the crawl History.  But when I try and get the crawl history (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloshm/archive/2009/03/31/how-to-programmatically-export-the-crawl-history-to-a-csv-file-in-powershell.aspx) using the below I don't seem to get an object I can really work with (its one big string container as far as I can tell) and it is full of IDs.

```
 $s = new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://portal");
 $c = [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchContext]::GetContext($s);
 $h = new-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlHistory($c)
```

I was hoping to get an object that represents the crawl history which I could then filter on crawl name and Type = full.

I have searched around and can't find an answer anywhere.  (Note also that the CrawlHistory class is being deprecated).

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  Just need to then call this:
$h.GetCrawlHistory() and parse it.